# Why am I not getting notified by email when my Find My iPhone is used?

Tags: email, find-my-iphone

I am not getting notified when the Find My iPhone app is used or even if I try searching via iCloud. How can I enable them?

Answer (score 1):

You only get notified if you:

1. Play a sound on the remote device
2. Put the remote device on Lost mode
3. Ask to be notified when it comes back online if the device is offline

Just watching the location of the device on the app or iCloud does not trigger a notification.

There may be ways of finding out, they are discussed in this [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/125921):

> However, your son could enable Status Bar Icon so that the device shows the location services icon in the status bar when the location tracking is active.
>
> Settings → Privacy → Location Services → Find my iPhone → Status Bar Icon
> This shows the normal location services icon (and not a special icon for Find my iPhone) if the device's location is being obtained through Find my iPhone.